# Is there any way to handle two errors type in same interface?

Tags: java

Say I have `ErrFoo` and `ErrBar` two different error classes in java. I have to handle them after you receive response in `RetryPolicy`? But Type info are erased in this level. I could not directly get error info in this layer.

I already came up with extractor solution but pretty ugly. In this way, I need add a same extractor function in all RPC call method from two layer above which is `ConcreteClient` because in that layer all types info are present. This is pretty ugly. I am wondering is there any way that I can create an interface or what is other way to solve my needs?

```
public class AbstractClient {
        protected <ReqT, ResT> void callAsyncWithRetry(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, ResT> method,
                                                   ReqT request,
                                                   StreamObserver<ResT> responseObserver) {}
}

public class ConcreteClient extends AbstractClient {
   // real call issue from here. 
}

public class RetryPolicy {
    public <T> T callWithRetry(Callable<T> proc, String methodName) {
        //error need to be handled here. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Too chaotic. I recommend you first read  **[how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and then edit your question accordingly to attract more people to your question.

Comment: Can you post some code? Are you looking for a try double catch block or something?

Comment: Yup. I know it is too chaotic. I am working on writing it. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I just updated my question's description. Sorry for the chaotic at first time. SK's editor is not every ease of use.